# How to make this type design any one Know That in android

Tags: android

Design Like circle Show in Activity How to make this type of design or what to call it Please Suggest Me

[image]

Comment: That looks like a static intro screen , Just take a complete image of it . Don't design intro screen unless you need some functionality in the calendar . If you looking on how to desing intro screens check this article https://www.javatpoint.com/android-introduction-slider-example

Comment: i am taking about circle area in image how to make upper side of view pager app lunch show information about tab icon please suggest

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3WDeUFy.png

Answer (score 1):

Its calleed FloatingActionButton in android you can add it in your activity xml